# Where can you view or query all your recent chat replies?

Tags: feature-request, chat

I don't know if this could an obvious suggestion which has already been taken into account or a totally stupid idea (or if it is already possible and I just could not find it) but several times I thought it could be useful to be able to query for at least latest chat message replies.

This is because it happens that I need to take a second look at something someone said to me in chat but I cannot sort it out.

So I thought to ask it directly here.

Answer (score 1):

They already show up in your inbox drop-down on any regular SE site, although only if you were not in chat at the time.

Are you looking for something different than that? If so, there's [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/109081/leggy7?userId=109081&tab=replies&StartDate=2016-08-21&EndDate=2016-08-26) recent replies view on [chat.stackexchange.com](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) itself. You navigate there by viewing your own chat profile and looking at the replies tab, which you can then filter.

Comment: I thought that dropdown menù displays only notifications which occurred while not browsing SE. Am I mistaking?

Comment: It looks like you're right; mine is usually so crowded I hadn't really noticed.

Comment: The dropdown displays pings that haven't been dismissed while you're not active in chat. You can be browsing the regular site. In most cases if you leave chat without dismissing them (replying/clicking the circle) you'll get a notification after some time.